# Can std::atomic_flag be used in a signal handler

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, atomic, signal-handling

According to the [C++17 standard, [support.signal]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/support.signal), the atomic object should satisfy the following requirements to be used in a signal handler:

> - [...], or
> - `f` is a non-static member function invoked on an object `A`, such that `A.is_­lock_­free()` yields `true`, or
> - `f` is a non-member function, and for every pointer-to-atomic argument `A` passed to `f`, `atomic_­is_­lock_­free(A)` yields `true`.

`std::atomic_flag` doesn't fit here formally (there is no `is_lock_free` method and `atomic_is_lock_free` can't be called with `std::atomic_flag` object). Though intuitively, it's very close (it's atomic and lock-free). Does it mean that `std::atomic_flag` can't be used in a signal handler, or it's just a C++ standard that needs clarification?

Comment: `std::atomic_flag` is always lock free, so it seems to me like it should be usable in a signal handler, but I agree that it doesn't seem legal by the current wording.  I don't see any existing standard defects relating to it.  Assuming no one more knowledgable than myself has a better answer, there are instructions for submitting a standard defect report [here](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-issue).

Comment: why do you need specifically atomic_flag? can you use atomic<bool>? their performance is exactly the same

Comment: @AndriyTylychko what to use in the signal handler is really out of the scope of my question, but yes, I just use atomic bool

Comment: Also, note that atomic_flag is guaranteed to be lock-free, unlike atomic bool, where you have to check lock-free in runtime with method is_lock_free. I guess in practice it's always true though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have pointed out is a defect in the standard that has been resolved in [LWG 3756 Is the `std::atomic_flag` class signal-safe?](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3756).

The new wording obviously allows for `std::atomic_flag` to be used in signal handlers:

> A [*plain lock-free atomic operation*](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.signal#def:plain_lock-free_atomic_operation) is an invocation of a function `f` from [[atomics]](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics), such that:
>
> - [...]
> - `f` is a non-static member function of class `atomic_flag`, or
> - `f` is a non-member function, and the first parameter of `f` has type *cv* `atomic_flag*`, or
> - [...]
>
> An evaluation is [*signal-safe*](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.signal#def:evaluation,signal-safe) unless it includes one of the following:
>
> - a call to any standard library function, except for plain lock-free atomic operations and functions explicitly identified as signal-safe;
> - [...]

It's probably safe to assume that `std::atomic_flag` is signal-safe in any standard prior to C++23 too, given that it's intended to be, and *basically* satisfies the requirements, even if not *technically*.